# switching between divs by click event

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code. Basically, what I like to do is, when clicked on cpu_div, I like to show the all_cpu div and when clicked on, all_cpu div, I like to show cpu_div. The idea is to switch between divs back and forth:

```
html code:

<div id="cpu_all"> </div>
<div id="cpu_div"></div>


       var serverA = "http://url/cpu.png";
       $("#cpu_div").click(function () {
        var myImage = new Image();
        $(myImage).load(function () {

            $('#all_cpu').show();
            $("#all_cpu").html(myImage);

        }).error(function () {
            $('#all_cpu').hide();
         }).attr('src', serverA)
    });

    $("#all_cpu").click(function () {
        $('#all_cpu').hide();
        $("#cpu_div").show();
    });
```

when clicked on cpu_div, it brings up all_cpu div but when clicked on all_cpu div, nothing is happening. Any one can chime in to see what is wrong here?

Comment: It would be ideal to take a look at your html. Could you assemble a jsfiddle?

Comment: html please. put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If its a newer version of jQuery, try `$("#all_cpu").on("click", function(e) { ...` else try `$("#all_cpu").live("click", function(e) { ...`

Comment: do you dynamically add #all_cpu to dom by any chance ?

Comment: $("#all_cpu").click(function () {
                $('#all_cpu').hide();
                

            });
this even not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#cpu_div, #all_cpu").on('click', function() {
    $("#cpu_div, #all_cpu").not(this).show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

If that's still not working, give this a go:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cpu_div, #all_cpu', function() {
    $("#cpu_div, #all_cpu").not(this).show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Also, using the native onload function would be a better idea in my opinion:

```
$("#cpu_div, #all_cpu").on('click', function() {
    var myImage = new Image();

    myImage.src = 'http://url/cpu.png';
    myImage.onload = function() {
         //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: nice attempting troubleshooting with out seeing any html , +1 for that , my guess was  the selector is wrong

Comment: @adeneo, not working. When I click on cpu_div, it brings up all_cpu div. But when want to go back by clicking on all_cpu div, nothing is happening. Not bringing up cpu_div.

Comment: @ScottSelby - Thank, it's impossible to tell what the problem is with questions like this, one just has to try and cover the basics, and hope something works?

Comment: @user1471980 - why are you responding to all these comments , and still not posting you HTML ?

Comment: @user1471980 - We're all just guessing blindly here, and assuming you know how to implement our answers. If you could stick your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it would make things a little easier.

Comment: I cannot post the code to jsfiddle, my work does not allow me. what I am trying to do is very simple. I have two divs with images. Clicking on my image loads the other div and hides itself and vise versa. I tried everything above, not working. My question is, I can load the image by defining it and sourcing it the first time. When I hide that div and then try to show it again, do I have to define and source it again? It seems like $('div_id').show() does not simply working.

Comment: If it's inside the load() function (which is deprecated), that only fires once, when the image is loaded. After that the load function will not fire again until the image is loaded once more, and that would normally take a new page load/refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adrian has suggested, we can't know everything that's going on without your HTML, but it sounds like you want to `toggle()` the visibility of those two divs

```
$("#all_cpu,#cpu_div").click(function () {
    $('#all_cpu').toggle();
    $("#cpu_div").toggle();
});
```

Comment: The answer from @adeneo seems more succinct.

Comment: when I click on #all_cpu div, nothing is happening. It is not loading #cpu_div.

Comment: they are all based on assumptions after all. they don't show whats wrong with his code.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi , agreed.  we have asked the OP to show their code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you set the attr('src') after you try to load the image.
Changing your code to

```
 $(myImage).attr('src', serverA).load(...)
```

will fix that.